# JSON Deserialize Error

Tags: vb.net, json, json.net

I wanna pass the json to server, below is the json format:

```
[{"StaffID":"S01","StaffRank":"Manager"},{"StaffID":"S02","StaffRank":"Waiter"}]
```

After I tried the following code to get the json array:

```
  Dim request As String = New StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd
    response = AddStaff(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of tbl_Staff)(request))
    Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response)
```

I get the new error which is:

> "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'tbl_Staff' because the type requires a JSON object
>   (e.g.{"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error
>   either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or
>   change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a
>   collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
>   be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
>   added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array."

What is the problem? Thanks

Comment: The error message seems fairly clear. What aspect is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.I just change the code to List. Then working perfectly.

```
Dim request As String = New StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd
response = AddStaff(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of tbl_Staff))(request))
Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'tbl_Staff' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.{"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

It seems like no matter how detailed I make that error message, people just don't read it :-\